# while using MySql, express, angular, nodejs, will the ports be different for express and node

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

While looking into express + node + mysql, tutorials suggest to start express server by using `node server.js` (here server.js contains logic to connect to mysql db), which calls upon app.listen() and angular+node tutorials start node server using `npm start`.

Are they different and I have to start both?
In case, yes, do I need to use diff ports?
In case, no, how to call upon mysql db? Please give some reference or elaborate.

server.js is as follows:

```
var express         =         require("express");
var mysql           =         require("mysql");
var app             =         express();
var connection      =         mysql.createConnection({
        host        :         "localhost",
        user        :         "userid",
        password    :         "password",
        database     :         "sakila"
});
connection.connect(function(error){
  if(error)    {
      console.log("Problem with MySQL"+error);
  } else {
      console.log("Connected with Database");
   }
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components/angular'));
app.get('/app/#/actors_load',function(req,res){
  connection.query("SELECT * from actor",function(err,rows){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Problem with MySQL"+err);
      } else {
          res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
      }
  });
});
app.listen(8000,function(){
  console.log("It's Started on PORT 8000");
});
```

My phonecatapp has following routers:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      when('/actors_load', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/actors.html',
        controller: 'ActorsCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

and controller looks like this:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('ActorsCtrl',function($scope, $http, $interval){
    load_names();
    console.log("ActorsCtrl");
    /*
    $interval(function(){
      load_names();
    },300);
    */
    function load_names(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8000/actors_load').success(function(data){
            console.log("kdfhg"+data);
          $scope.actors=data;
        });
    };
});
```

the partials of html has a link to populate the db data as:
`<div><a href="#/actors_load">actors</a></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing trial and error, I found that srever.js is on server side, angular part of the project is on client side. from angular part, only way to recieve data is using REST API. This role of providing REST API will be facilitated by server.js and hence shall be run on diff port. It means I had to call `npm start` as well as `node server.js`. Then I was facing CORS issue, which I resolved by providing

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

in server.js. NOte that to see the effect of this code, you need to start the two servers. This was really a pain point for me. I spent whole day trying various combinations in various places to resolve CORS issue. It seemed not to be working. For some reasons, I stopped the servers and restarted, it was working. After few trials, I realized that even after removing above code, it was working. So, I stopped servers again and this time it was not working, that is how I realized it.

One more thing that I was mingling the two thinking them as one project having client and server side. Any newbie, please understand that client side accesses server side as REST API, so develop them as separate module/project. Do not develop as single module/project.

Answer (score 0):

> `npm install` doesn't start a server. It is a command to install packages.

In this particular example the `createServer` function will accept connection on port `8000`. it's taken from `node.js` docs.

```
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

As soon as the above code is executed the server is ON. `express` is a framework for `node.js`. `express` creates server on the top of `node.js` so the `express` configuration (along with port number) will be executed by `node.js`. Specified `port` of `express` server will run an instance of `node.js` server, that's the end of the story

---

To connect to `mysql` you can use one of the `mysql` packages for `node` e.g.:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : '< MySQL username >',
  password : '< MySQL password >',
  database : '<your database name>'
});

connection.connect();
```

In above case you are using `localhost` as a adress of your database.

> You can find plethora of `mysql` packages on `npm` site: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mysql

You may also use `mysql.createClient` for costumised connection:

```
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: '??',
  password: '??',
  port: 8889
});
```

> Note: remember to `require` your packages otherwise they just simply won't work.

Comment: `npm install` was meant to be `npm start`. First I have built angular + node project, that is working with npm start. Then I sought M*EAN project and this starts with `node server.js`. After integration, I tried to run the project with `npm start`, hoping server.js router will work. It did not. With `node server.js`, angular part of the project is not working. server.js is provided in the question now.

Comment: npm - node package manager, it's has nothing to do with your `.js` files. Sever will run as soon as `.j` file with your configuration will be executed.